# Google App Script Big Query - GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Query parameter 'X' not found

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now and I felt like I should reach out. This might be very simple but I am not from a programming background and I haven't found any resources to solve this so far.

Basically, I want to parameterize a SQL query that is running for BigQuery within Google APp Script, it takes a variable from a user from a Google From they have submitted and I wanted to ensure that this won't be injectable by parameterizing the query, however, I got the following error that I could not fix:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Query parameter 'account_name' not found at [1:90]

Here is how I run the query:

```js
//Query
const sqlQuery = 'SELECT district FROM `table` WHERE account_name = @account_name AND ent_theatre=("X") LIMIT 1;'
          
const request = {
  query: sqlQuery,
  params: { account_name: queryvar },
  useLegacySql: false,
};
          
// Run Query
var queryResult = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request,projectID);
```

I have created the query based [on Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#node.js)

Comment: I forgot to add how I define the query from the parameter, its up in the code and its basically

var company_name = ss.getRange(lastrow, 3).getValue();
var queryvar = '"'+company_name+'"';

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for `request` object is not correct. The right syntax for the `BigQuery.Jobs.query` Request is like below:

```js
  const request = {
    query: sqlQuery,
    queryParameters: [
      {
        name: "account_name",
        parameterType: { type: "STRING" },
        parameterValue: { value: queryvar }
      }
    ],
    useLegacySql: false,
  };
```

For more detail about `QueryRequest` Object refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#queryrequest).

Comment: This was it. Odd that google's one showed something different though..

Thank you very much! Wish you the best!